# How to count occurrence of each word on each line?

Tags: powershell

I'm stuck as I have to use Powershell at work. I've attached my code and results so far below.

```
$data = Get-Content "/Users/mikeshobes/Documents/Powershell/nfl.csv"

write-host $data.count total lines read from file
foreach ($line in $data)
{
    write-host $line
}
```

---

```
13 total lines read from file
1,Tom Brady,NE,QB,93,142,65.5,47.3,"1,137",8,379,7,3,55,38.7,48,17,3,9,97.7
2,Matt Ryan,ATL,QB,70,98,71.4,32.7,"1,014",10.3,338,9,0,54,55.1,73T,13,2,8,135.3
3,Aaron Rodgers,GB,QB,80,128,62.5,42.7,"1,004",7.8,334.7,9,2,53,41.4,42T,17,1,10,103.8
4,Ben Roethlisberger,PIT,QB,64,96,66.7,32,735,7.7,245,3,4,35,36.5,62T,8,3,2,82.6
5,Russell Wilson,SEA,QB,40,60,66.7,30,449,7.5,224.5,4,2,22,36.7,42,5,2,6,97.2
6,Dak Prescott,DAL,QB,24,38,63.2,38,302,7.9,302,3,1,16,42.1,40T,3,1,2,103.2
7,Eli Manning,NYG,QB,23,44,52.3,44,299,6.8,299,1,1,12,27.3,51,3,2,2,72.1
8,Matt Moore,MIA,QB,29,36,80.6,36,289,8,289,1,1,16,44.4,37,3,0,5,97.8
9,Matthew Stafford,DET,QB,18,32,56.3,32,205,6.4,205,0,0,10,31.3,30,3,0,3,75.7
10,Alex Smith,KC,QB,20,34,58.8,34,172,5.1,172,1,1,9,26.5,24,3,0,1,69.7
11,Brock Osweiler,HOU,QB,14,25,56,25,168,6.7,168,1,0,9,36,38,1,0,0,90.1
12,Connor Cook,OAK,QB,18,45,40,45,161,3.6,161,1,3,11,24.4,20,1,0,3,30
13,Julian Edelman,NE,WR,0,1,0,0.3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,--,0,0,0,39.6
```

Comment: [SO] isn't a script writing service. To get help you should first show your own coding effort. To give you a start look at `Get-Help` with `Get-Content`, `ForEach` and `Measure-Object`

Comment: What are your expected results given that sample? I see nothing in your code except you writing each line of the file to screen. Have you tried something else? What are you considering as a word?

Answer (score 0):

if what you want to get is the amount of times every word in a line is in that line, first you need to split the line in words an then get the amount of times that word is in that line.

I think a snippet of code explain it better:

```
For ($i = 0; $i -lt $Data.Length; $i++) {
   $Line = $Data[$i]
   Foreach ($Word in $Line.Split(' ,')) {
      Write-Host ('Line {0} contains the word: "{1}" {2} time(s)' -f ($i + 1), $Word, (($Line -split $Word).Count-1))
   }
}
```